# Count rows containing combinations in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, combinations

Assuming I have the following dataframe which is made up of characters 'a' through 'e':

```
df <- data.frame(P1 = c("a","b","c"), P2 = c("b","c","d"), P3 = c("e","a","e"))

  P1 P2 P3
1  a  b  e
2  b  c  a
3  c  d  e
```

I want to count the number of dataframe rows that contain each combination (size 2) of 'a' through 'e'. So in this case there are 10 different (size 2) combinations of 'a' through 'e'.

```
t(combn(c("a","b","c","d","e"),2))

    [,1] [,2]
 [1,] "a"  "b" 
 [2,] "a"  "c" 
 [3,] "a"  "d" 
 [4,] "a"  "e" 
 [5,] "b"  "c" 
 [6,] "b"  "d" 
 [7,] "b"  "e" 
 [8,] "c"  "d" 
 [9,] "c"  "e" 
[10,] "d"  "e"
```

2 rows have the combination "a" & "b", 1 row has the combination "a" & "c", no rows have the combination "a" & "d" and so on ......... ultimately I want a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   X1 X2 Count
1   a  b     2
2   a  c     1
3   a  d     0
4   a  e     ..
......... etc
```

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated, I was thinking dplyr or similar might have something suitable but haven't managed to work out an easy approach without a time consuming loop or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the data in long format and create the combinations for each row, count the combinations and join it with data which we created for all combinations to get missing values.

```
library(dplyr) #dplyr >= 1.0.0
library(tidyr)

ref_data <- as.data.frame(t(combn(unique(unlist(df)),2)))

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(value = combn(sort(value), 2, toString)) %>%
  separate(value, c('V1', 'V2'), sep = ", ") %>%
  ungroup %>%
  count(V1, V2) %>%
  right_join(ref_data, by = c('V1', 'V2')) %>%
  mutate(n = replace_na(n, 0))


# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   V1    V2        n
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a     b         2
# 2 a     c         1
# 3 a     e         1
# 4 b     c         1
# 5 b     e         1
# 6 c     d         1
# 7 c     e         1
# 8 d     e         1
# 9 a     d         0
#10 b     d         0
```

Comment: Looks to be exactly what I want, although I'm getting an error ""Error: Column `value` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 3"" after the following line `summarise(value = combn(sort(value), 2, toString))`

Comment: Yes, for this to work you'll need dplyr 1.0.0. You can update `dplyr` package. If you have trouble updating the package you can replace `summarise` line with `summarise(value = list(combn(sort(value), 2, toString)))  %>% unnest(value) %>% separate.......rest of the code`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I updated to 1.0.0 and still struggled but the alternative line of code works perfectly fine.